# Invocable Method for REST API May Return Problem

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, callout, fault-connector

Good Morning,

I have written an [Invocable Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) that calls my own REST API using a [Callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts.htm), which is working well as a Screen Flow Action used to place orders in an external system. Next, I must implement some fault/error/exception handling. I'm struggling to find much information on this topic.

1. In a Flow that calls an [Invocable Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm), one can have a Fault path. This path is used when the Action throws an Exception. I believe `$Flow.FaultMessage` will contain the message field of the exception?
2. I have built "standard" REST API that uses [Problem Details for HTTP APIs (RFC 7807)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) to return errors, thinking I was future-proofing myself. But how do I take a problem received by my Invocable Method, from my REST API, and pass it to the Flow with more than just a "message", since I can not return a different result object for errors than I do for actual results.

What do you recommend as a best practice for this?

Thank you,

A.

Comment: On your point #2 you can actually return different objects for success and failure, but only if you define your REST API method as void return and explicitly set the RestResponse body yourself, like `RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(apexClassInstanceResponse));`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PhilW! I'm doing it the other way around: calling an external REST API from inside an Apex Invocable Method. It's the return on the latter that I need to figure out.

Comment: That's generally achievable by having all possible success and failure values in your Apex POTATO (Plain Old Transactional Apex Transient Object) and then having code that looks for failure vs success content.

Comment: (That's if you're not using HTTP response statuses to indicate failures, which is what I would recommend.)